# Issues with Moving Visual Studio 2017 Solution from one GitHub account to a new Github account

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, github

I previously was hoping to use TFS with Visual Studio 2017 (VS) and Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS), but Microsoft removed the TFS option from VSTS and replaced it with DevOps, anyways all was not lost, I was able to open  GitHub account for my version control, and added the GitHub extensions to my Visual Studio 2017, works great, just as simple to use as TFS with VS 2017. I am really happy about Microsoft Acquisition of GitHub and integration with VS 2017.

I had a paid developer account on GitHub for $7 month, and it worked great, at https://github.com/ABION-Technology/, but now Microsoft made a change to where the free GitHub accounts are almost identical to the previous developer version, so I created a new free Github account at https://github.com/Michael-G-Workman/, I wanted to move my public repos to the new free account from the Abion Technology account. Using the TRANSFER option in GitHub, I transferred my BLOGGING repo to the new free GitHub at https://github.com/Michael-G-Workman, no problem.

However the issue I have is when I try to Sync the Blogging solution to the new Github in Visual Studio, it generates an error where it is still expecting the VS solution BLOGGING to be at https://github.com/ABION-Technology/, instead of the new Github account at https://github.com/Michael-G-Workman/, it generates the following error output:

```
C:\Users\New User\source\repos\Blogging
Commit 32344f00 created locally in repository C:\Users\New User\source\repos\Blogging
Remote: Permission to ABION-Technology/Blogging.git denied to Michael-G-Workman.
Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
unable to access 'https://github.com/ABION-Technology/Blogging.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Also it appears that git is in my Visual Studio 2017, but the Git tools like Git Bash are not, when I try to install the Git Tools, there is nothing available for Git except the GitHub extensions in TOOLS->EXTENSIONS & UPDATES.

I think there is probably a very simple fix to correct this issue, but do not know what the fix would be

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a simple solution to this problem, in TEAM EXPLORER in Visual Studio 2017, Click on the following SETTINGS->REPOSITORY SETTINGS->EDIT, note screenshots, like many Visual Studio issues, a very simple fix, changed the paths from https://github.com/ABION-Technology/ to https://github.com/Michael-G-Workman/

[image: SETTINGS 1]

[image: SETTINGS 2]

[image: SETTINGS 3]

[image: SETTINGS 4]